# "pdfMake" Bangla font breaking the word on "এ-কার"

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdfkit, pdfmake, bangla-font

Bangla words are breaking on 'এ-কার' after generating the PDF using `pdfMake`

[image]

> **I have tried so many different fonts to check but got the same issue**